# Add less than symbol, "<", to a ggplot via geom_text in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

**The short version**: How would I make this contrived code plot a proper greek beta character AND the rest of the label string, with the space and the less than character and the numbers formatted as typed?

```
library("ggplot2")
df<-data.frame(a=1:15,b=6:20)
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=a,y=b)) + geom_point() +
       geom_text(x=5,y=4,label="beta=1.00 p<0.0001", parse=TRUE)
```

If I leave out the ", parse=TRUE" argument, the string works great, but won't give me a real greek beta. If I leave it in, all hell breaks loose.

---

**The long version** (and why I can't find a duplicate): I finally discovered in [How to use Greek symbols in ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293715/how-to-use-greek-symbols-in-ggplot2) that methods for placing greek characters on a ggplot depends upon where you're putting them. Since I am using geom_text to force strings of text onto the body of the plot, my attempts to use expression(beta) have failed and I recently started using the parse argument mentioned above. I came across [How can I add alpha-numeric AND greek characters to geom_text() in ggplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9248881/how-can-i-add-alpha-numeric-and-greek-characters-to-geom-text-in-ggplot), which I thought was my answer, but fixing the "space" resulted in extra parentheses popping in, "=" replaced by a comma, and loss of formatting for all of my previously formatted text numerics.

A link to a guide for using the parse argument, and how to make sense of what seems to me to be completely unintuitive would be very helpful to me, and probably future R users ending up here. Many searches have been fruitless.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should do it:

```
g <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=a,y=b)) + geom_point()
g + annotate("text", x=5,y=4,parse=TRUE, label="beta==1.00 * ' p<0.0001'")
```

It's a matter of splitting the label with single quotes to the side of the whitespace and connecting two label bits with `*`.  You also need the `==` for equals to.

[image]

Comment: Great information! Thanks! Two additions from my experimenting with it: Single quotes around the '1.00' allow me to keep my sigfigs. And I noticed that this works with both annotate() and geom_text(), other answers suggest reasons for using annotate() for this particular need. Any suggestions on a guide to this grammar? I can now make this example work, but still don't understand it for future needs that may arise.

Comment: not sure about a definitive guide to grammar - but this plotmath helpfile is useful for learning what syntax to use:  https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/plotmath.html

Comment: `label="beta==1.00 * ~italic(p)~ ' < 0.0001'"` for italic p